# How would I get output from the pop-up images thats being clicked in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of images where they randomly come up on the screen, and the user is required to click on the images that applies to them. 
Now what I need is How would I monitor which image they clicked so as the developer I know which images apply to them? I can also make something like a list of images they clicked on the bottom of the screen.

Would anyone show me directions on how would I go on doing this because I don't have a clue to where to start from. Thank you

**This is how I generated the random images**

```
var imageArray = new Array(); 
imageArray[0] = new Image(); 
imageArray[0].src = "football.png"; 
imageArray[1] = new Image(); 
imageArray[1].src = "painting.png"; 
var randomImage = imageArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length)]; 
var hobby = new Bitmap(randomImage);
```

Comment: Show us how you're generating a random number to get the image and display it

Comment: Show us the code you have so far?

Comment: Can you use jQuery or do you prefer pure JS?

Comment: Sorry,I've been trying it to make it work on jsfiddle but I couldn't. I uploaded it to codepen but the output doesn't work however the code is the same. 
The 'showHobby()'  function used for the images to come op on the screen randomly in random positions. 'hobbyhit()' and 'showalert()'functions count the times clicked on the images and alerts it at the end. 
You can look at the code from here
http://codepen.io/hTeeML/pen/NqeBgv

Comment: @Ayrit I can use both

Comment: @ hTeeML Example won't run.  You're missing a certain js library in your example code.  Perhaps you're using pixi.js or phaser.js?

Comment: I am using easel and tween.js and I added them both but it doesn't work for some reason. However the javascript code is the exact one that I am using on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is give each of the images an ID, I would probably give them numbers.

Then adding this to your script for each image.

```
document.getElementById(insert image id here).onclick = function() {
    //Enter what happens when the user clicks the image here. 
};
```

You can also do it using jquery like so:

```
$("#insert image ID").click(function(){
    //Enter what happens when the user clicks the image here.
});
```

There is probably a better way to do this, but I cant really imagine it right now :)